# PHPUnit, coverage report showing non-code line as not covered?

Tags: php, phpunit

I've got a unit test that's acting funny. The test passes, but the code coverage report shows one particular line, which is a comment, to be - not covered, and this affects the code coverage statistics:

[image]

The definition for the class being tested looks as follows:

```
class User implements UserInterface, \Serializable
```

When I remove the **, \Serializable** part, the problem disappears, but then my code will break in other ways, which is not a solution.

Does anyone have an idea why this could be happening?

```
phpunit --version
```

**PHPUnit 3.6.11 by Sebastian Bergmann.**

Comment: Maybe it's warning that it never returns a value?

Comment: I tried removing the @return, but it has no effect.

Comment: When I remove the @param line from the comment the problem disappears, but then that's the docblock and phpcs down the drain.

Comment: Another observation I made is when I remove the implements \Serializable part from my class, the problem completely disappears.

Comment: I've created a bug report on Github: https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/php-code-coverage/issues/101

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a bug in the PHPUnit token stream parser and the behavior is definitely not in any way expected.

I don't think you can do more than what you already did by creating the bug report.

Comment: I agree, I'll leave the code as is, and wait for the next update from the developers.